# CNN output accuracy below 50%

Tags: python-3.x, conv-neural-network, unsupervised-learning

I am new with using unsupervised CNN model in python. I am trying to use CNN model for image classification with unsupervised spectrogram input images. Each image is of size 523 width  and 393 height. And I have tried the following code

```
    X_data = []
files = glob.glob ("C:/train/*.png")
for myFile in files:
    image = cv2.imread (myFile)
    image_resized = misc.imresize(image, (523,393))
    image_resi = misc.imresize(image_resized, (28, 28))
    assert image_resized.shape == (523,393, 3), "img %s has shape %r" % (myFile, image_resized.shape)
    X_data.append (image_resi)

X_datatest = []
files = glob.glob ("C:/test/*.png")
for myFile in files:
    image = cv2.imread (myFile)
    image_resized = misc.imresize(image, (523,393))
    image_resi = misc.imresize(image_resized, (28, 28))
    assert image_resized.shape == (523,393, 3), "img %s has shape %r" % (myFile, image_resized.shape)
    X_datatest.append (image_resi)

input_img = Input(shape=(28,28,3))  

x = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(input_img)
x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)
x = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)
x = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
encoded = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)

x = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(encoded)
x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
x = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
x = Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu')(x)
x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
decoded = Conv2D(3, (3, 3), activation='sigmoid', padding='same')(x)

autoencoder = Model(input_img, decoded)
autoencoder.compile(optimizer='adadelta', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
X_data = np.array(X_data)
X_datatest = np.array(X_datatest)
##print('X_data shape:', X_data)   

X_data= X_data.astype('float32') / 255.
X_datatest = X_datatest.astype('float32') / 255.
X_data = np.reshape(X_data, (len(X_data), 28, 28, 3))  # adapt this if using `channels_first` image data format
X_datatest = np.reshape(X_datatest, (len(X_datatest), 28, 28, 3))  # adapt this if using `channels_first` image data format

hist=autoencoder.fit(X_data, X_data,
                     epochs=5,batch_size=128,verbose = 2,validation_data=(X_datatest, X_datatest))
##                callbacks=[TensorBoard(log_dir='/tmp/autoencoder')])
avg = np.mean(hist.history['acc'])
print('The Average Training Accuracy is', avg)
```

But the output is 33% only for the accuracy. I don't know why. Can anyone help me with this and try to make me understand the numbers of filters, kernels and the resize with 28*28 based on what? And why we just use the image size which is here 523 width  and 393 height?

Comment: It is because you are passing the same dataset as both features and labels `X_data`.

Comment: @MassoudHosseinali because i don't have labels,, its unsupervised data .. what can i set as labels instead of X_data?

Answer (score 0):

1. We are not using the image size 523x393. In the code you can see that the 28x28 image is always getting appended to X_data and X_datatest. I dont see any reason to first resize to 523x393 and then again resize to 28x28. (bad copy-pasta maybe?)
2. The model you are trying to train is an autoencoder. Basically the first part of the model (*encoder*) will try to "encode" the input image as some abstract vector of numbers (`encoder` in the code). The aim of the model is to learn a good conversion scheme between the image and this abstract vector so that this vector of numbers also contains all the features of the images.

   The model learns to do this by decoding this in the second part. The `decoder` is the output that is the same dimensions as the image, and if the model is trained perfectly, should exactly match the input image.
3. Now the parameters of the model. Well, it varies from model to model. You can decide on :

   - the input image dimensions
   - the number of layers you want
   - the number of filters in each layer
   - the kernel size of each filter

   and a lot more. The only constraint for this autoencoder model is that the `decoder` dims should match the `input_img` dims.

Try reading on some CNN tutorials to know how these works. It will take time and cant be covered in one post.

You should also look at the source of this autoencoder code and see the corresponding paper. It will have a much better insight into the choice of these parameters.